# How to add "whats this" property to QInputDialog?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to add a "whats this" value to a QInputDialog box, specifically getInt.

I am not sure how to do this and the documentation hasn't helped me. I have tried this:

```
tmp = QInputDialog()
tmp.setWhatsThis('What is this?')
self.seed = tmp.getInt(self, 'Seed', 'Please enter the RNG seed now', self.seed)[0]
```

However when I click the little question mark on the dialog box nothing happens. I think I could do this by making a custom class but that seems like a lot of work for something so simple.

Comment: `getInt` is a static method. It ignores the instance you've created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this when using the [static functions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#static-public-members) like `getInt`. You need to do everything manually:

```
dialog = QInputDialog(self)
dialog.setWindowTitle('Seed')
dialog.setLabelText('Please enter the RNG seed now')
dialog.setInputMode(QInputDialog.IntInput)
dialog.setIntValue(self.seed)
dialog.setWhatsThis('What is this?')
if dialog.exec() == QDialog.Accepted:
    self.seed = dialog.intValue()
```